# CAML Query to pull list items only if their approved?

Tags: list, workflow, sharepoint-enterprise, caml-query, caml

Although the solution seems relatively strightforward it doesnt seem to work.

Here is my CAML query to pull all items from a list that have been approved through the OOTB Sharepoint Approval Workflow.

I have named the workflow "Approval", but when I build the queries in U2UCAML Query Builder or CAML Designer they seem to display "Announce" in place of "Approval"....weird. I tried replacing it with Approval and executing it but it dint fly.

Please advise.

```
<Query>
<Where>
  <Eq>
     <FieldRef Name='Announce' />
     <Value Type='WorkflowStatus'>Approved</Value>
  </Eq>
</Where>
</Query>
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using U2U CAML Query Builder in a lot of cases it's easier to build the query by creating a view using the SharePoint UI. When you get the view right the use [SharePoint Manager](http://spm.codeplex.com) to look at the Query of the View.

In case of the status of the Approval workflow it may be a little complicated as what you want to check for isn't the text Appoved, but the status value of [16](http://www.dzeee.net/sharepoint/post/2010/04/06/Workflow-status-codes-%28used-for-view-filter%29.aspx)

So you query ends up something like:

```
<Where>
  <Eq>
    <FieldRef Name="Approval" />
    <Value Type="WorkflowStatus">16</Value>
  </Eq>
</Where>
```

Comment: "16" worked great! Is there an official Microsoft site I can find these mappings? For example what I would use in place of "In Progress"? Thanks!

Comment: I haven't found an "official" list, but have you see the link at "16" in my answer?

Comment: oops! I am sorry I dint notice the link in all the excitement. Thanks again